# Pushing a non-repeating string into stack and printing its size in java

Tags: java, stack

As you can see I am getting an issue here as I am trying to insert a non-repeating string into my stack using two loops but while compiling I am getting this Error -
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
The method push(String) in the type Stack is not applicable for the arguments (char)

```
import java.util.*;
public class Qno3String {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inp=sc.nextLine();
        Stack<String> st = new Stack<>();
        for(int i =0;i<inp.length();i++) {
            for(int j = i;j<inp.length();j++) {     
                if(inp.charAt(i) == inp.charAt(j)) {
                    st.push(inp.charAt(i));
                }
            }
        
        }
        System.out.println(st.size());
    }

}
```

Comment: that just means that you cannot push a char. charAt returns a char, your stack expects a String. What did you think would happen?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you the problem: push an integer, not a char.

```
st.push((int)inp.charAt(i));
```

---

Note that the error message and your code are contradictory:

```
Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<>();
```

but:

> The method push(String)…

Comment: @user16320675 the error message and the code is kind of contradictory...